# How to properly mock and test a $window.variable in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Maybe I don't see it clearly, but I wonder:

> How to mock and test a `$window` variable?

I use the `$window` in the following function:

```
vm.showCampaignDetails = function(campaignId) {
  vm.someFunction({ position:$window.pageYOffset });
  $state.go('campaignDetails', { campaignId: campaignId });
};
```

I call showCampaignDetails from a ng-click inside my view:

```
<button ng-click"vm.showCampaignDetails(campaignID)">Details</button>
```

> Now I want to unit test this function. But no matter what I do, I
>   cannot mock the value of `$window.pageYOffset`.

I tried to pass it via the function, but this seems to be silly.

So, how could an approach look like?

This is my test:

```
it('should navigate to campaign details and save the scrolling position', function () {
  spyOn(vm, 'someFunction');
  spyOn($state, 'go');

  $window.pageYOffset = 1998;

  vm.showCampaignDetails(13);

  expect(vm.someFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ position: 1998 });
  expect($state.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('campaignDetails', { campaignId: 13});
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mock the $window dependency:

```
var windowMock = { pageYOffset: 0 };

beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
     $provide.value('$window', windowMock);
  }));
```

Comment: argh, faster than me! Good Job :)